# Android APK not deploying to AVD

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I seem to be unable to deploy my Android application to an AVD for testing.  Gradle compiles my app fine, and nothing seems wrong with the application, but it won't deploy to AVD.  Here's my output:

From Run monitor:

> The APK file C:\Users\Erica\Documents\Lyle&[]apos;s Programming\AndroidCalc\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk does not exist on disk.
>   Error while Installing APK

(the [] in the path is not in the original message, I put it there because otherwise StackOverflow would format it as an apostrophe, and I wanted to make sure it didn't get formatted to show that it was using the character code rather than an apostrophe literal)

I checked in Windows Explorer to see if the file existed at that location (replacing the char code with an actual apostrophe), and it absolutely does, in fact it's the only file in that folder.  I wonder if perhaps it can't find it because of the apostrophe.  Is that an issue, or is it something else?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was the apostrophe.  I changed the name of that folder and it worked.